Is it just a coincidence that 2187 and 2197 are so close?
I noticed that $3^7 = 2187$ and $13^3 = 2197$. So, a fun way to combine these is:
$$\left(10+3\right)^{3} = 10+3^{10-3}$$
If Pillai's conjecture holds, then such a difference of $10$ between perfect powers only occurs in finitely many cases. But the difference of $10$ isn't fully what makes the result interesting. I'm having trouble articulating exactly why I find this identity surprising, but hopefully others can agree that it is unusual.

Is there a meaningful way to generalize this, or to generate similar results? Or is it just a coincidence?

What about $125 (5^3)$ and $128 (2^7)$? :-)

@Dominique Nice! And to put it in a similar format, we can write $$5+5^{5-2}=2+2^{5+2}$$

Our tour includes the counsel, “Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.”

@PaulTanenbaum Similar questions have generated answers, for example this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213737 . But perhaps you are correct that my question currently is not specific enough. Maybe the general form of such identities is: $$A+B^C=D+E^F$$ where $$\left{A,B,C,D,E,F\right} \subset \left{0, a, b, -a, -b, a+b, a-b\right}$$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$. If that is a reasonable reformulation, then maybe I should ask a new question about that general form.

I don't recall where I saw this (it's on MSE), but it is well known that $c=a^7-a=b^3-b$ has the solution $a=3, b=12, c=2184$. I think that the specific format you can fit these numbers into is most likely coincidence.
